# How to reduce Overpass way QL statement output to just tags?

Tags: performance, overpass-api

I am new to Overpass API. Ran this query [way(around:10.0,37.559391,-122.301529);out;] in overpass-turbo.eu and getting lot of information about nodes. I just need to know whether it is valid way or not and does not require any other information such as node. Other purpose is not reduce the time taken below 10ms, currently i have local instance of Overpass which is taking more than 300ms. I want to run this query for 1 Millions records per day, it seems it wont be possible with this response time.

Tried with following approaches.

1. using union queries.
2. using custom wiki.

Still not able to reduce to response time. Please suggest.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a local Overpass API instance installed, you may run as many queries in parallel as your hardware can handle, e.g. by configuring the rate-limit parameter for your dispatcher process accordingly:

```
--rate-limit=number: Set the maximum allowed number of concurrent accesses from a single IP.
```

Then 300ms per call may be a non-issue altogether. Please give it a try and report back your results.

Concerning the data volume: if you replace `out;` by `out ids;` or `out tags;`, Overpass API will just return the OSM way ids (assuming some ways were found). For all available output options, please consult the [documentation in the OSM wiki](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#Print_.28out.29).

Comment: I have local overpass api instance installed for north america, I will work to get multiple concurrent requests. But i need all the tags for way since i need maxspeed and address from that data, so just getting ids won;t work for me. Would migrating to DB and using Nominatim or others API help ?

Comment: Why don't you use the "add a comment" to leave a comment? You're not restricted to `out ids;` - you could use `out tags;` as well. Just take a look at the documentation as I pointed out.

Also, you didn't mention before that you need addresses. That's an entirely different use case, which you cannot handle by Overpass API in most cases.

Comment: Please do not use the area reserved for direct answers to your question to make comments or ask new questions.  At your <50 reputation your best bet may be to use the **edit** button to revise your question, but if that will invalidate any existing answers then you need to ask a new question.  Please take the [Tour] if you have not already.